# What is the scenario to make wsHttpBinding an alternative for netTcpBinding

Tags: c#, wcf, https, nettcpbinding, wshttpbinding

We use netTcpBinding in an asp.net webforms intranet application.

On the client machines we have activeX (winforms) running which retrieves its data via wcf.

The activeX container is inside the asp.net application.

What advantage/benefit do we have from using wsHttpBinding over netTcpBinding?

Comment: See [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709047/nettcpbinding-or-wshttpbinding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709047/nettcpbinding-or-wshttpbinding)

Answer (score 2):

The primary benefit of using wsHttpBinding would be that you could embed your WCF server within IIS, and then use IIS to encrypt the transmission between the client and server.  It also allows you to avoid firewall issues and use port 80 for the communications with the server.

Comment: It's possible to entirely self-host wsHttpBinding with encryption as well, no need to use IIS for that. IIS does, however, make things a bit easier with certificate registration against the local machine store.

Comment: I would add that using wsHttpBinding gets you the benefit of a standard implementation of WS-Security for authentication as well. WS-Reliable Messaging is also included but is probably less commonly used.

Comment: @Mike Do the clients have to install a certificate when using wsHttpBinding(https) ?

Comment: @Pascal: Clients only need to provide a client-cert if you set your wsHttpBinding configuration to do so. The property is Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Certificate. Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789011.aspx

Comment: Thanks Mike but I do not want to set that ;-)